Removing carriage returns and line breaks from specific columns in excel using VBA
I have a code that does it but it works on all columns and some of my files take a very long time to clean up. Is there a way to either speed up this code or make it work on 7 specific columns that my team uses for analysis.
Here is a code I am using right now (some files it takes just a few seconds others over 25 min):
Sub RemoveCarriageReturns2()
   Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        cel = Application.Substitute(Application.Substitute(CStr(cel), vbLf, vbCr), vbCr, " ")
    Next
End Sub

specific columns that I am interested in are: NAME, ADDRESS, STATE, ZIP, SPCIALTY, NPI & TIN.
thanks

Instead of looping through all the cells in the UsedRange, loop through the cells in the relevant columns

I am just starting with vba, can you give me an example how to do it?

For each cel in Application.Intersect(UsedRange, Range("A:A")) where A is the column you want to loop through may give you better results. I tend to go with something like For each cel in Range("A1:A" & LastRow) where LastRow is a variable containing the last used row in the column

The problem is that columns are not in the specific order . They come in different columns on different spread sheets. The only thing in common are the headers.

See here

Replace Strings

VBA has its Replace function which you could (should) use instead of Excel's Substitute Worksheet function.

It is assumed the used range (rg) has one row of headers.


Whole Worksheet

You should be able to get away with the following simple code.

Sub TestWholeWorksheet()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange
    
    rg.Replace vbLf, " ", xlPart ' usually it's not 'vbCrLf' !?
 
End Sub

Specific Columns

Not sure if you'll increase efficiency be narrowing it down to specific columns.   You'll have to test it (share some feedback).

Main
Sub TestSpecificColumns()

    Dim COLUMN_TITLES() As Variant: COLUMN_TITLES = VBA.Array( _
        "NAME", "ADDRESS", "STATE", "ZIP", "SPCIALTY", "NPI", "TIN")

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.UsedRange
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = RefMatchingColumns(rg, COLUMN_TITLES)
    If crg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    crg.Replace vbLf, " ", xlPart ' usually it's not 'vbCrLf' !?
 
End Sub

Help
Function RefMatchingColumns( _
    ByVal rg As Range, _
    ByVal ColumnTitles As Variant) _
As Range
    
    Dim hrg As Range, drg As Range, RowsCount As Long
    
    With rg
        RowsCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If RowsCount = 0 Then Exit Function ' no data
        Set hrg = .Rows(1)
        Set drg = .Resize(RowsCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Dim ColumnIndices As Variant:
    ColumnIndices = Application.Match(ColumnTitles, hrg, 0)
    
    Dim urg As Range
    
    If IsArray(ColumnIndices) Then
        
        Dim crg As Range, c As Long
        
        For c = 1 To UBound(ColumnIndices)
            If IsNumeric(ColumnIndices(c)) Then
                Set crg = drg.Columns(ColumnIndices(c))
                If urg Is Nothing Then
                    Set urg = crg
                Else
                    Set urg = Union(urg, crg)
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    
    Else
        
        If IsNumeric(ColumnIndices) Then
            Set urg = drg.Columns(ColumnIndices)
        End If
    
    End If
        
    Set RefMatchingColumns = urg
    
End Function

